# JMX or not to JMX

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, spring-jmx

That's the question.

And just like good old Hamlet, I'm seeking the one answer that fits me. Or rather fits my program's need.

Basically what I want is this: I want to present some data about my running Quartz jobs in a nice and intuitive way to a user. The data I'm talking about is number of messages processed and whether or not the job is running, or in case there was an error, the last error message.

Would Horatio be able to give me an answer on how to achieve this in the easiest possible manner?

Is JMX the right way of thinking, or should I rather venture in the, for me unknown land, of JSP sites with spring mvc?

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMX is not designed to be accessed by end users.

Comment: Ok. In that case, I'd rather opt for web-mvc. Thank you